# objects sequence change with array filter method (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

I have the below array of objects named `getRecommendations`. I will be using this to map the data which i will be receiving from backend.

```
const getRecommendations = [
 { 
  recoTitle: "Retire",
  recoDescription: "Its time to retire and relax with family"
 },
 {
  recoTitle: "Buy home",
  recoDescription: "Start saving to buy home in near future"
 }
]
```

Below  is the array of recommendations i receive from backend and it is in sequence of ranks. for e.g. `Buy home` is rank 1 and `Retire` is rank 2 in this case. sometimes it may be other way around. I want to display the recommendations in the same order as i receive from the backend to the UI display.

`const recommendations = ["Buy home", "Retire"];`

But i do the following mapping because i not only need `recoTitle` but also `recoDescription` to display the user. I have `getRecommendations` which does a mapping of recoTitle and recoDescription. The below code is used to get both in the array of object. It is as follows

```
const filteredReco = getRecommendations.filter(
  ({ recoTitle}) => recoDetails && recoDetails.indexOf(recoTitle) !== -1,
);
```

now, if i see the contents of `filteredReco` by using console log, `Retire` will come as a first object and then `Buy Home`. How can i ensure the order of listing is not affected by the way i use filter. Can someone please suggest.

Comment: This is because you are iterating the getRecommendations, and the sequence is based on that. If you want to maintain the order in recommendations, you need to rewrite the logic to loop throuh each item in recommendation array and fetch the matching obj from getRecommendations

Comment: ```recommendations.map(recName =>  getRecommendations.find(rec => rec.recoTitle === recName))```

something like this?

Comment: @igk- Yes, this worked. thanks. Can you post it as an answer too. Might help someone

Comment: yes, ofcourse. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recommendations.map(recName =>  
   getRecommendations.find(rec => rec.recoTitle === recName)
)
```